# Is there a way that we can maintain a json in FHIR?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I wanted to store a JSON in FHIR. JSON can be anything, for example, it can be something like

```
{
   assignee: "PCC OFF SHORE",
   dueby: "30-03-1991",
   description: "This will be assigned to PCC off shoure"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store any arbitrary data as a Binary resource in an Attachment data type (e.g. DocumentReference or in an extension).  Technically, you could also put it in a string data type, but that wouldn't be terribly appropriate as strings are not expected to be parseable.

Answer (score 0):

Certain FHIR resources accept elements of type `value[x]`. That type accepts variations like `valueString` or `valueCode`. For your case, `valueBase64Binary` may be a good alternative.

Read: https://www.hl7.org/fhir/extensibility.html#extension